# Show div and create elements any time a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show `div#options_holder` and create some elements inside it by using this code:

```
var counter = 1;

$('#choices').on("change", ":checkbox", function(e) {
    var theName = $(this).attr('name');
    var theID = $(this).attr('id');
    var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
    var input, button, append = "";

    $("#options_holder").show();

    input = capitalize(theName) + '<input name="input_' + theName + '[]" id="' + theID + '" value="" placeholder="' + capitalize(theName) + '" />';
    button = '<button type="button" class="add-size">Nuevo ' + capitalize(theName) + '</button>';

    append = counter === 1 ? input += button : input;

    $("#options_holder").append(append);
    counter++;

    console.log("You changed " + theName + ", with an id of " + theID + ", its checked property is: " + isChecked);
});
```

But it does not work since `div#options_holder` remains hidden and elements aren't created, is something wrong? It's supposed that those should happen any time I mark a checkbox, if I unmark in the other hand the process should be reverted meanind `div#options_holder` will be hidden and any element inside it should be destroyed, what's wrong?

Comment: #choices has to be in DOM at time you are setting the onchange handler. Is the event fired or not?

Comment: @A.Wolff it's on DOM just hidden, is that a problem? Why?

Comment: Try wrapping in a $(function() {<<your code here>>});

Comment: @IvanL this is just a part of a big JS file and all are wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){ .... });`

Comment: @Reynier no, element hidden is not the problem. But you didn't answered: Is onchange event fired or not?

Comment: @A.Wolff in fact I was wrong `#choices` is always visible since there is where checkboxes are, the hidden is `#options_holder`

Comment: @Reynier and you still didn't answer my question... At least knowing if event is fired or not would help to resolve your issue...

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, event is fire since I get this output at console: `You changed talla, with an id of talla_choice, its checked property is: true`, `You changed color, with an id of color_choice, its checked property is: true`, `You changed talla, with an id of talla_choice, its checked property is: false` forget about name since I translate from spanish to english to give more readability

Comment: I created a simple fiddle with your code and it seems to work there... http://jsfiddle.net/pXJpr/

Comment: @IvanL upssss something is really wrong since I have the same code, I'll check

Comment: To all, thanks for your replies but was my mistake, I was calling `#choices_holder` and in my HTML code I had `.choices_holder` that's was the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure that your selectors work and your IDs are correct are often easily overlooked. Glad we could help you find your typing mistake :-)

Working code fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pXJpr/

HTML:

```
<div id="choices">
    <input type="checkbox" name="testName" id="testId" />
</div>
<div id="options_holder" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var counter = 1;

$('#choices').on("change", ":checkbox", function(e) {
    var theName = $(this).attr('name');
    var theID = $(this).attr('id');
    var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
    var input, button, append = "";

    $("#options_holder").show();

    input = capitalize(theName) + '<input name="input_' + theName + '[]" id="' + theID + '" value="" placeholder="' + capitalize(theName) + '" />';
    button = '<button type="button" class="add-size">Nuevo ' + capitalize(theName) + '</button>';

    append = counter === 1 ? input += button : input;

    $("#options_holder").append(append);
    counter++;

    console.log("You changed " + theName + ", with an id of " + theID + ", its checked property is: " + isChecked);
});

function capitalize(s) {
    return s;
}
```